# Do I need a comma before "since" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Most of the boys in our class shared my hatred for Tom(,) since he was cruel and violent.

Comment: You need the comma if *since* in the second clause is meant to be explanatory (i.e., meaning "because") and not a time expression.

Comment: @Robusto Yes, it acts as "because" not "when." Weird, not even the premium version of Grammarly underlined it as incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write in two ways :

1) Most of the boys in our class shared my hatred for Tom since he was cruel and violent.

2) Since Tom was cruel and violent,  most of the boys in our class shared my hatred for him.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The M in "Most" should be lowercase - just a nitpick.

Comment: You can write this in more than two ways. OP shouldn't have accepted this answer.